# UT000010: Session is invalid with Wildfly 23 and Pac4J

Tags: wildfly, google-signin, pac4j

I am working on a JEE 8 application, where i want to use Googles authentication mechanism (OAuth2) for an easier registration process of new users.

This is my project setup:

- deltaspike 1.9.5
- pac4j 3.8.3 (using Google2Client)
- Java 11
- Wildfly 23

The configurationcode for Pac4J

```
private Config getConfig() {
        Config config = new Config("/callback", 
                getDirectFormClient(), 
                getJwAuthClient(), 
                getGoogle2Client());
        config.getClients().setUrlResolver(new JaxRsUrlResolver());
        config.getClients().setAjaxRequestResolver(new JaxRsAjaxRequestResolver());
        
        SessionStore<JaxRsContext> sessionStore = new ServletSessionStore() {

            private HttpSession applicationSession;

            public HttpSession getHttpSession(JaxRsContext context) {
                if (applicationSession == null) {
                    assert context instanceof ServletJaxRsContext;
                    applicationSession = ((ServletJaxRsContext) context).getRequest().getSession();
                }
                return applicationSession;
            }

        };
        config.setSessionStore(sessionStore);
        return config;
    }
```

The login via google works for some minutes, but then i get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT000010: Session is invalid ZBZm3NBmhjxSoyrzJyjPD5jVXoqXccctmVILioYd
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.server.session.InMemorySessionManager$SessionImpl.getAttribute(InMemorySessionManager.java:519)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final//io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpSessionImpl.getAttribute(HttpSessionImpl.java:122)
    at deployment.jakartaee-8-backend.war//org.pac4j.jax.rs.servlet.pac4j.ServletSessionStore.get(ServletSessionStore.java:32)
    at deployment.jakartaee-8-backend.war//org.pac4j.jax.rs.servlet.pac4j.ServletSessionStore.get(ServletSessionStore.java:18)
    at deployment.jakartaee-8-backend.war//org.pac4j.core.profile.ProfileManager.retrieveAll(ProfileManager.java:81)
    at deployment.jakartaee-8-backend.war//org.pac4j.core.profile.ProfileManager.getAll(ProfileManager.java:59)
    at deployment.jakartaee-8-backend.war//org.pac4j.core.engine.DefaultSecurityLogic.perform(DefaultSecurityLogic.java:102)
    at deployment.jakartaee-8-backend.war//org.pac4j.jax.rs.filters.SecurityFilter.filter(SecurityFilter.java:55)
    at deployment.jakartaee-8-backend.war//org.pac4j.jax.rs.filters.AbstractFilter.filter(AbstractFilter.java:42)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:308)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:398)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:365)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:338)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.15.1.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:440)
    ... 59 more
```

Does somebody had the same problem?
Should i use a newer wildfly or a newer pac4j library?
Thanks for any hint :-)

yours
Shane

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like an issue with pac4j.  The HttpSession instance referenced by ServletSessionStore needs to be invalidated when the session expires.

Answer (score 0):

after i upgraded to wildfly 26.1.3 and pac4j 5.7.2 i still got the problem.
I got a step further by initialysing Pac4J with this:

```
@Override
public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
    context
        .register(new JaxRsConfigProvider(getConfig()))
        .register(new Pac4JSecurityFeature())
        .register(new WildflyPac4JProfileInjectorFactory()) 
        .register(new ServletSessionStoreProvider(getConfig()))
        .register(new ServletJaxRsContextFactoryProvider());    
    return true;
}
```

Then i could remove the setting of the session store.
It is important to get the **location header** inserted in the **401 response**.
Therefore i did:

```
 JaxRsAjaxRequestResolver ajaxRequestResolver = new JaxRsAjaxRequestResolver();
    ajaxRequestResolver.setAddRedirectionUrlAsHeader(true);
    config.getClients().setAjaxRequestResolver(ajaxRequestResolver);
```

The problem now is, that after the Google-Profile selection screen it causes the Exception:

```
 INFO  [org.pac4j.oauth.client.Google2Client] (default task-1) Failed to retrieve or validate credentials: State parameter mismatch: session expired or possible threat of cross-site request forgery
```

is there anybody who could send any hints?

yours Shane